# Восстановление записи в формате wav по характеристикам полученным функциями из библиотеки librosa

Tags: python, librosa

Есть озвученные фрагменты текста и текст к этим фрагментам голосом 1.
То же самое есть и для голоса 2. Тексты идентичны.
По голосу 1 и голосу 2 я могу получить все доступные характеристики которые дает библиотека librosa. Вопрос такой. Можно как то на основании характеристик для голоса 2 поправить голос 1.
То есть конечная цель обучить нейросеть чтобы другие тексты озвученные голосом 1 преобразовывались в озвучку голосом 2 ? Я читал про разработку Vera Voice. Про программу разработанную Deep Mind (они написали программу Альфа Го).

Comment: Вам придётся много читать, тут вам вряд ли кто на пальцах так ответит. Насколько я понимаю, это называется "перенос стиля". Наверняка есть что-то готовое на `Tensorflow` или `Keras`, но чтобы это применить вам всё-равно придётся разбираться в нейросетях не на поверхностном уровне

Comment: Разбираться в нейросетях это совсем другой вопрос. Допустим я в них как то разбираюсь. Вопрос к тем кто занимался обработкой звука. По сути это обратная задача и вопрос в том, имея характеристики голосов построить фильтр   преобразования. Кто то занимался?